# how to pass parameter with quotation marks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can do this in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  'C:\myPC.file', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

but how do I do this?

```
Declare @Var = 'C:\myPC.file'
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  @Var, SINGLE_BLOB)
```

I tried three `'''` single quotes, but still says incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not parametrise [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) (or OPERNQUERY etc). Constants only.

```
Declare @Var = 'C:\myPC.file';
Declare @SQL varchar(1000);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @Var + ''', SINGLE_BLOB)';
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: This example does not work. it says: Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  'c:\MyPC.file', SINGLE_BLOB)'