# Fastest Data Transferring Over A Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When it comes to transferring data between linked servers, there have been several method I have used in my work to date.

I'm wondering if there is an accepted fastest/most efficient way that a task like this should be handled? Or are there different situations when one should be used over another?

I have used:

**OpenQuery**

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM OPENQUERY([server]......
```

**OpenRowset**

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'Server=[server].......
```

**TempTable / SP**

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
EXEC [server].[db].[dbo].[storedprocedure] @Param1, @Param2
```

After some 'googling' I haven't got a definitive answer... Or is there another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important bit is to ensure that the remote query is actually executed remotely.

This *will* happen with the temp table/sp route.

For the other 2 options, it may pull all data locally before any sorting/filtering etc. 
Whether it does this depends on the linked server settings. However they have other faults too

- you can't control linked server settings with OPENROWSET because it is adhoc
- OPENQUERY and OPENROWSET do not allow parameters: only string constants

So, option 3 is the best route

For more, see

- [how to pass parameter with quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070142/how-to-pass-parameter-with-quotation-marks/8070161#8070161) (about OPENQUERY)
- (DBA.SE) https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6862/630

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've tested this out - and yes, it definitely makes a difference to execute the procedures remotely.